# PHP reshedule time/appoiment based on edit or new entry

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have data in grid for time schedule when Edit update/re-schedule whole time table based one new entry.

For example

If change last entry then using mysql update all record and re arrange time.

If i change last record to 1.30 to 2.30 than all affected record should be re-arrange.

[image: Time table]

Comment: Your question isn't within the scope of stackoverflow. It'll take some work to manipulate following records. You should also supply what you've tried.

Comment: @Darren I tried to fetch record and update based on new **to time**, but record selection for update and my algorithm logic is not working as excepted